# Setter не устанавливает значение

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Делаю приложение на Spring Boot. В сервисе мне нужно в цикле проставить объектам (`vehicle`) значения (`int`), взятые из другого объекта (`fuelData`).
Вот этот метод сервиса:

```
public List<Vehicle> findAllVehicles(boolean searchForTrailers) {
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = vehicleRepository.findAllVehicles(searchForTrailers);
        for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
            if (!vehicle.isIndividualFcr() && !vehicle.isTrailer() && findCurrentFuelData() != null)
                System.out.println("CFD is " + findCurrentFuelData().getConsumptionRate());
                vehicle.setFuelConsumptionRate(findCurrentFuelData().getConsumptionRate());
                System.out.println("FCR is " + vehicle.getFuelConsumptionRate());
        }
        
        return vehicles;
    }
```

Но значения почему-то не проставляются и `FCR is`  выводит `0`, хотя `CFD is`  выводит правильное значение (`35`).
На всякий случай проверил `setter`, вписав в него `System.out.println("SETTER IS DONE");` - это тоже выводится в консоль.

Stacktrace:

```
CFD is 35
2023-09-25T14:08:38.705+03:00 DEBUG 20180 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        f1_0.id,
        f1_0.consumption_rate,
        f1_0.start 
    from
        fuel f1_0 
    where
        f1_0.start=(
            select
                max(f2_0.start) 
            from
                fuel f2_0 
            where
                f2_0.start<=current_date
        )
Hibernate: 
    select
        f1_0.id,
        f1_0.consumption_rate,
        f1_0.start 
    from
        fuel f1_0 
    where
        f1_0.start=(
            select
                max(f2_0.start) 
            from
                fuel f2_0 
            where
                f2_0.start<=current_date
        )
SETTER IS DONE
FCR is 0
2023-09-25T14:08:38.706+03:00 DEBUG 20180 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL
```

Сеттер:

```
    public void setFuelConsumptionRate(Integer fuelConsumptionRate) {
        this.fuelConsumptionRate = fuelConsumptionRate;
        System.out.println("SETTER IS DONE");
    }
```

Сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fuel")
public class FuelData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate start;
    private Integer consumptionRate;
    
    public FuelData(){}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDate getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(LocalDate start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public Integer getConsumptionRate() {
        return consumptionRate;
    }

    public void setConsumptionRate(Integer consumptionRate) {
        this.consumptionRate = consumptionRate;
    }
    
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicles")
public class Vehicle {
    
    private static transient boolean displayTrailers = false;
    private static transient int commonFuelConsumptionRate;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean trailer;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "character varying (30)")
    private String make;
    @ManyToOne
    private Type type;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "character varying (30)")    
    private String model;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "character varying (20)")
    private String number;
    private Long remainingFuel;
    private Long speedometerReading;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean individualFcr;
    private Integer fuelConsumptionRate;

    
    public Vehicle(){}
    

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public boolean isTrailer() {
        return trailer;
    }



    public void setTrailer(boolean trailer) {
        this.trailer = trailer;
    }



    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }


    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }


    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }



    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }



    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }



    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }



    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }



    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    public static boolean isDisplayTrailers() {
        return displayTrailers;
    }


    public static void setDisplayTrailers(boolean displayTrailers) {
        Vehicle.displayTrailers = displayTrailers;
    }



    public Long getRemainingFuel() {
        return remainingFuel;
    }


    public void setRemainingFuel(Long remainingFuel) {
        this.remainingFuel = remainingFuel;
    }


    public Long getSpeedometerReading() {
        return speedometerReading;
    }


    public void setSpeedometerReading(Long speedometerReading) {
        this.speedometerReading = speedometerReading;
    }



    public boolean isIndividualFcr() {
        return individualFcr;
    }


    public void setIndividualFcr(boolean individualFcr) {
        this.individualFcr = individualFcr;
    }


    public Integer getFuelConsumptionRate() {
        if (!individualFcr) return commonFuelConsumptionRate;
        return fuelConsumptionRate;
    }


    public void setFuelConsumptionRate(Integer fuelConsumptionRate) {
        this.fuelConsumptionRate = fuelConsumptionRate;
        System.out.println("SETTER IS DONE");
    }


    public static int getCommonFuelConsumptionRate() {
        return commonFuelConsumptionRate;
    }


    public static void setCommonFuelConsumptionRate(int commonFuelConsumptionRate) {
        Vehicle.commonFuelConsumptionRate = commonFuelConsumptionRate;
    }


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "trailer_types")
    public static class Type {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        @OneToMany
        private List<Vehicle> trucks;
        
        
        public Type(){}

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Vehicle> getTrucks() {
            return trucks;
        }

        public void setTrucks(List<Vehicle> trucks) {
            this.trucks = trucks;
        }           
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас метод-геттер `getFuelConsumptionRate()` содержит какое-то условие - проверьте, оно точно выполняется, чтобы выдать именно то значение, которое вы хотите?

Comment: Блин, опять я в грязь лицом ударил :) Спасибо, помогло

Comment: На будущее: геттеры-сеттеры имеют простой и общепринятый функционал. В идеале сеттер только устанавливает значение, геттер - только выдаёт. Отсюда и их канонические названия - `setField()` и `getField()`. Если в них заложена какая-то дополнительная работа - то это желательно отражать в названии (и да, тогда они перестанут быть обычными геттерами-сеттерами). Например, `setFieldAnd...()` и `getFieldAnd...()`. Возможно, это не обязательно делать, когда в сеттере проводится какая-нибудь просто валидация, но если у вас геттер возвращает два разных поля - то это точно должно сказываться на названии.

Comment: Так, например, ваш геттер мог бы называться `getFuelOrGetCommonFuelIfSomething()`.